# Common practice of __new__ constructor?

Tags: python, constructor

I know (?) about theory behind `__new__` constructor in Python, but what I ask about is common practice -- for what purpose is this constructor **really** (!) used?

I've read about initializing immutable objects (the logic is moved from `__init__` to `__new__`), anything else? Factory pattern?

Once again, please note the difference:

- for what task `__new__` can be used -- I am not interested
- for what tasks `__new__` **is** used -- I am :-)

*I don't write anything in Python, my knowledge is from reading, not from experience.*

Where you can actually answer the question: [Common practice of **new** constructor?](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1zt37p/common_practice_of_new_constructor/)

Comment: You are basically asking for a list here; examples that show how `__new__` is to be used. That makes the question primarily opinion based and too broad and most of all, off-topic. As such, I have voted to close it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please educate me. I wrote that I am **NOT** interested how it **COULD** be used, yet, you comment that I **AM** interested how it could be used. What is the phrase in English, that everybody understand the difference between theory and practice, because I have no clue? Thank you. For the second part, I didn't ask about your opinion is usage X is good or bad, I asked about facts (example: "Python is used for web development", this is the fact no matter who think what about that).

Comment: @Martijn It's not opinion based. It's a good technical question of design background rooted in the __new__ constructor. It's actually a very good question

Comment: @StefanoBorini: asking for a common practice is asking for opinions, as everyone has a different opinion on what common practice entails.

Comment: Voting for reopen. In any case, new creates the instance that will then initialized in init. It's a great place for do some magic all your objects are created. A real use case I've seen is in django model objects, where you declare the fields the class has and the accessor methods are created automatically. In pratice, this is not done through new, but through metaclass, which is an extension of new

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am pretty sure that the gang of four design patterns are no opinion.

Comment: @Stefano I agree with Martijn - this is still off-topic/too broad. It's asking for a list of where `__new__` is used... The answer is it's used in all sorts of places for varying things. If it was a specific problem with the actual usage of one of those methods then it'd be different and it would be on-topic.

Comment: @JonClements, both you are saying this is sooooo broad, yet, so far nobody wrote a single answer. So maybe your fear comes a bit too early? Please calm a bit, wait a little, and we will see what happens next, OK?

Comment: @greenoldman that's the entire point of too broad... There's not an actual answer that can solve a specific problem you have because you *don't have a specific problem*. The SO Q&A engine is not geared towards building lists... There are old questions kept for historical purposes that were effectively lists, but it's not on-topic for SO these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of `__new__` is to create an empty object instance that `__init__` then initializes.  Reimplementing `__new__` you have full control of the instance you create, but you stop short of actually using the `__init__` method to do any further processing. I can give you two cases where this is useful: automatic creation of methods and deserialization from disk of a class with a smart constructor. These are not the only ways you can solve these two problems. Metaclasses are another, more flexible way, but as any tool, you have different degrees of complexity you may want to get.

**Automatic creation of methods**

suppose you want to have a class that has a given set of properties. You can take control how these properties are initialized with code like this

```
class Foo(object):                                                                                                                                    
    properties = []                                                                                                                                   
    def __new__(cls, *args):                                                                                                                          
        instance = object.__new__(cls, *args)                                                                                                         
        for p in cls.properties:                                                                                                                      
            setattr(instance, p, 0)                                                                                                                   
        return instance                                                                                                                               

class MyFoo(Foo):                                                                                                                                     
    properties = ['bar', 'baz']                                                                                                                       

    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                               
        pass                                                                                                                                          



f=MyFoo()                                                                                                                                             
print dir(f)
```

the properties you want are directly initialized to zero. You can do a lot of smart tricks, like doing the properties list dynamically. All objects instantiated will have those methods. A more complex case of this pattern is present in [Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), where you declare the fields and get a lot of automatic stuff for free, thanks to `__new__` big brother, metaclasses.

**Deserialization from disk**

Suppose you have a class with a given constructor that fills the fields of the class from an object, such as a process:

```
class ProcessWrapper(object):                                                                                                                         
    def __init__(self, process):                                                                                                                      
        self._process_pid = process.pid()                                                                                                             

    def processPid(self):                                                                                                                             
        return self._process_pid
```

If you now serialize this information to disk and want to recover it, you can't initialize via the constructor. So you write a deserialization function like this, effectively bypassing the `__init__` method you can't run.

```
def deserializeProcessWrapperFromFile(filename):                                                                                                      
    # Get process pid from file                                                                                                                       
    process = ProcessWrapper.__new__()                                                                                                                
    process._process_pid = process_pid                                                                                                                
    return process
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If I not mistaken both cases stem from the fact you cannot change object properties in `__init__` -- having this limitation removed (for example C# `readonly` fields can be written not only directly, when declaring them, but also in constructor) it would render `__init__` without a job, right?